# Apache POI not "Saving" excel file

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am writing a small utility that creates a pivot table in an excel sheet using POI and I want to read the data from the pivot table back to the program which will save it as a PDF file using Itext. I am running into a problem where the program cannot read the data from the pivot table after it is created. The program only can "see" the information in the pivot table after I manually open the created file and hit the save button in excel. Does anyone know a way to read the data from the pivot table from the XSSFPivotTable object or otherwise force a way for the file to "save" so it can be accessed by the program again?

Here is a snippet of code so you can see what I'm talking about. I'm a student so any advice on best practices would be greatly appreciated as well.

```
public void returnPivotData() throws IOException {
    FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(this.xlsxFile);

    XSSFWorkbook book = new XSSFWorkbook(fs);
    XSSFSheet dataSheet = book.getSheet("Sheet1");

    AreaReference dataRef = new AreaReference("A1:E15",
            SpreadsheetVersion.EXCEL2007);

    XSSFPivotTable table = dataSheet.createPivotTable(dataRef,
            new CellReference("A16"));

    table.addRowLabel(0);
    table.addColumnLabel(DataConsolidateFunction.SUM, 3);

    // Save the data back to the file
    FileOutputStream fsOut = new FileOutputStream(
            "D:\\workspace\\test.xlsx");
    book.write(fsOut);
    fsOut.close();

    book.close();
    fs.close();

    // This does not allow access
    FileInputStream fsIn = new FileInputStream("D:\\workspace\\test.xlsx");
    XSSFWorkbook bookNew = new XSSFWorkbook(fsIn);

    XSSFSheet sheet = bookNew.getSheet("Sheet1");

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        XSSFRow rowNew = sheet.getRow(i);

        XSSFCell cellNew = rowNew.getCell(0,
                MissingCellPolicy.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);

        System.out.println(cellNew.toString());
    }

    fsIn.close();
    bookNew.close();

}
```

Comment: The [XSSFSheet.createPivotTable](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFSheet.html#createPivotTable-org.apache.poi.ss.util.AreaReference-org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellReference-) as well as the whole `XSSFPivotTable` is in [Beta](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/util/Beta.html) state until now. Your problem is not with saving but with rendering the pivot table in the sheet. This rendering is not be done from `apache poi` until now. `Excel` is doing this while opening the file.

Comment: So without opening with `Excel` the only solution would be doing the rendering yourself. But this will be the same effort as creating the PDF data from the data source yourself. So I would rethink the approach using a pivot table. It is only useful if the pivot table will be needed in the Excel too and not only for creating the PDF.